# CDN changes URLs to cdn.example.com

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo, cdn

I am testing a CDN. All the website URLs are being changed from `www.example.com` to `cdn.example.com` and this will lead to a SEO drop.

I have followed the procedure and asked the support service, with no result.

The only thing I could do is add a forced canonical to `www.example.com` on all pages, although I think this will not resolve.

Comment: Which CDN provider are you using?    And just to confirm, you want to have your ENTIRE site behind the CDN as opposed to just the resources such as images?